# hover effect in a dropdown menu in the navbar element in MBD(material design bootstrap)

Tags: css, mdbootstrap

I had a menu bar in header (code below), menu items were displayed on mouse hover.

After including MDB(material design bootstrap), this code stopped working on mouse hover. How to make menu item displayed on mouse hover with MDB.

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-material-design@4.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap-material-design.min.css" integrity="sha384-wXznGJNEXNG1NFsbm0ugrLFMQPWswR3lds2VeinahP8N0zJw9VWSopbjv2x7WCvX" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-material-design@4.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap-material-design.js" integrity="sha384-CauSuKpEqAFajSpkdjv3z9t8E7RlpJ1UP0lKM/+NdtSarroVKu069AlsRPKkFBz9" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>$(document).ready(function() { $('body').bootstrapMaterialDesign(); });</script>


<li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a href="" class="nav-link" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" title="" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button"aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        <img src="" class="img-responsive" height="28" width="28">                      
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
        <a class="dropdown-item">Personal</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item">Account / Password</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item">My Social Networks</a>                     
    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Welcome to the StackOverflow community! Could you phrase the question more clearly? For example, what are you trying to achieve with the hover effect, and what is the issue you are currently experiencing? Perhaps include a screenshot of the UI issue.